# tabindex -1 not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, tabindex

I am testing an application in firefox. When I hit tab it focuses the body of Firefox. If I it tab again then the next item in header. Now while next item is having focus if I do shift + tab it goes back to body and if I do shift + tab again it comes back to same item. It didn't move focus to address bar and goes in loop between body and next item if I keep pressing shift + tab.

I added code at body since it shows me focus at body when i checked for active element

```
  %body{tabindex: -1}
```

I tried using `tabindex: -1` and `-moz-user-focus: ignore` at body but no luck. I dont get this issue with other browsers.

Any idea how do I fix this issue?

Comment: `tabindex: -1` - that looks like you're trying to set the tabindex in CSS - having said that, I can't ever get body to get focus using tab/shift-tab, so you must've done something wrong in your code

Comment: sorry i am new to this. I added tabindex -1 in the html.haml file. is there a different attribute i can use?

Comment: `I added tabindex -1 in the html.haml file` - sorry, but I have no idea what that means - perhaps show the relevant piece of "code" - *preferably added into the question because in a comment code is generally unreadable*

Comment: %body{tabindex: -1}     This is where i added tabindex. when i check for document.activelement it shows me the focus is at body

Comment: `tabindex` is an HTML attribute. You must add it directly to the HTML, as in:  `<input type="text" tabindex=2>`. It can also be set via JavaScript like this: `objectReference.tabIndex = 2;`. The `<body>` element can't receive the focus in the first place. Your syntax is completely wrong.

Comment: perhaps you need to explain a bit more about your source environment, because `%body{tabindex: -1}` is not HTML, CSS or JAVASCRIPT - and the attribute is `tabIndex` - note the CAPITAL I

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is completely wrong.

`tabindex` is an HTML attribute. There are two ways to set this:

- Add it directly to the HTML, as in:  `<input type="text" tabindex="2">`
- It can also be **[set via JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/tabIndex)** like this:
  `objectReference.tabIndex = 2;`

The `<body>` element can't receive the focus in the first place, so I'm not sure what you are seeing there.

Lastly, there are known issues with Firefox and tabindex:

- [Why Won't Tabindex Work with Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846868/why-wont-tabindex-work-with-firefox)
- [Firefox tabindex not following source order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725835/firefox-tabindex-not-following-source-order)

Here's [an article](http://www.alexlande.com/articles/cross-browser-tabindex-woes/) that discusses cross-browser tabindex